# Method frame - how local variables array is created?

Tags: function-pointers, bytecode, local-variables, callstack, function-call

My question is most likely platform/compiler/language specific, but I will try to be as generic as possible.

When we call a method, a **frame** is created for it and we (usually/always) allocate some space for the local variables in an array, return address, and probably some other stuff depending on the platform we're on. We would also have our PC pointing to the first item of the function's **bytecode array**. My question arises here...

That bytecode array only includes opcodes and their operands (right?). In this case, when the relevant method has been called, the os/runtime should have an idea about how much space does it need to reserve to create the local variable array. I think that information is probably part of the class file that was already compiled. So, where's that size information stored actually? Is it part of the method's bytecode array (in addition to the opcodes and operands)? Or it's kept somewhere else?

To make the question more clear, perhaps this example might help. For example, when I call a function object, what I'm returned is the address of the first opcode/instruction in the method or the address of something that helps me to initiate the method frame?

Multiple approaches are more than welcome.

Hope my question is clear

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear which language/platform you're talking about, but in the case of Java classfiles, the size of the "local variable" table is stored as a field in the Code attribute of each method that has code.

That being said, modern JVMs operate at a higher level of abstraction. They don't just blindly interpret the bytecode - they may analyze and optimize the bytecode, or even compile it into machine code.

Comment: I didn't mean any platform/language. Nevertheless, your answer is almost what I was looking for.  Each method_info structure has a 'Code' attribute and that attribute contains all the information needed by the runtime during the execution. Do you have any idea on how a function call is performed - like how runtime utilizes that information in class files to setup a function frame in the thread stack? I think it's more architecture related thing (calling conventions, ABI). Perhaps that might be a separate question.

Comment: That's an implementation detail. Look at the VM source code if you're curious.